# Importacion Plantillas a Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

soy nuevo en el tema de Wordpress, les agradeceria me ayudaran a solucionar el siguiente problema que tengo, para un tema universitario necesito montar una pagina web sencilla en mi hosting y encontre unas plantillas .zip para importarlas en WordPress pero al instalarlas me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo trate de subir por FTP y el WP lo que muestra es otro error el cual es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor les agradezco cualquier luz que me puedan dar para solucionar esto, es un trabajo de la universidad.

Comment: El tema lo descargaste o pertenece a tu escuela?
Algunas veces hay errores al instalar temas por qué el archivo Styles.css no esta en la carpeta raíz del theme o porque el proyecto esta dentro de 2 carpetas por ejemplo Proyecto.zip/proyecto/proyecto-folder.

Comment: El tema lo descargue, pero teniendo en cuenta el ejemplo que pones, yo al descomprimirlo quedo asi Proyecto.zip/proyecto/proyecto-folder, pero lo saque del subdirectorio y la ruta quedo asi,  Proyecto.zip/proyecto-folder, y lo monte al FTP, veo que el css style.css esta en una subcarpeta llamada css

Comment: Pero te sigue dando el mismo error? De ser así necesitas mover el Style.css a la carpeta principal del proyecto de acuerdo a la documentación que he leído.

Comment: Ya lo hice e igual sigue el error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo el theme que quieres instalar es un child theme (tema hijo), osea que tienes que instalar el theme 'padre' para poder usar ese theme. Puede que el theme 'Elegant' necesite de otro para poder usarse.

Normalmente los themes que son así en el archivo style.css viene el theme que necesitas, un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vienen las dos partes señaladas, revisa el archivo style.css del theme

**Actualización:**

Haciendo pruebas, el error es causado por la falta del archivo `index.php` en el theme, intenta generar el archivo (poniendo código HTML con la información del theme o simplemente generando el archivo), o vuelve a obtener el theme ya que está incompleto.

Comment: Estuve mirando el archivo style.css y no encontre por ninguna parte en donde el indique que tipo de plantilla es, te voy a subir el css para ver si depronto me puedes dar otra luz.

Comment: Muy bien, estaría genial que subieras mínimo el encabezado del `style.css` @FernandoLopezOcampo

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R3bA8GbOoa0-N2W6Ba016wYsPhjnVewS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Viendo tu archivo, necesitas poner información dentro de `style.css`, parte de la información que puse en la respuesta, pero sin las líneas 4 y 15 (de la imagen)

Comment: Estoy revisando y creo que te faltaría el archivo `index.php` en tu theme, hice pruebas y quitando el `index.php` me sale el mismo error. Puedes informarme si es el index o es el style @FernandoLopezOcampo

Comment: que pena, no entendi bien, en el directorio raiz de la plantilla no hay ningun index.php, y en el style.css tampoco hay una  linea donde referencie algun index.php

Comment: Listo @FernandoLopezOcampo, el error entonces sería que no existe el archivo `index.php`, haz un archivo index.php y vuelve a comprobar. Si te sigue saliendo el error, el theme que tienes está mal entonces, vuelve a conseguir el theme.

Comment: Efectivamente al crear un index.php en blanco ya monta la plantilla correctamente en WordPress, pero sale en blanco, que me recomiendas para crear ese php o la plantilla tiene que obligatoriamente venir con ese php?.

Comment: Sí, tiene que venir con el `index.php` no necesariamente con contenido, pero en tu caso sí debe de tener contenido, revisa el theme original y revisa si existe el index.php, si no existiera comunícate con quien hizo el theme.

Comment: Amigo Mil gracias, me ayudaste full con mi problema, ya voy a mirar con el creador de la plantilla el tema del php, gracias.